# How to set border and scroll bar color for h:selectManyListbox

Tags: html, css, jsf

I want to set the border color and scroll bar color to red for my h:selectManyListbox

```
    <h:selectManyListbox id="abc" style="">
    </h:selectManyListbox>
```

Comment: Do it for a plain HTML `<select>` component. Then, ship those styles in a CSS class and apply it to your `<h:selectManyListbox>`.

Answer (score 0):

After some search, `scrollbar-base-color` is only Internet Explorer valid, you will need some JavaScript for FireFox and Chrome...

Here is informations about doing it : [Custom ScrollBar](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar)

As for the border, you can simple use that :

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="abc" style="border: 1px solid red;">
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

or

CSS :

```
.customSelect
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JSF :

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="abc" styleClass="customSelect">
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

or of course a simple selector :

```
select
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: that did not help for the scrollbar though

Comment: Have you followed the link at the top?